# How can I graph sine and cosine functions in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Hi I'm using numpy and matplotlib to calculate and graph sine and cosine functions because I was looking for python projects for beginners in google and found one I was interested in which was graphing a sine and cosine curve from -360º to 360º and 180º between them. I tried my best to solve the problem but I'm not sure I did it correctly, so can you help me and maybe explain how can this be achieved?

This is what I tried:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(-360,360,180)
sine = np.sin(x*np.pi/180)
cosine = np.cos(x*np.pi/180)

plt.plot(x,sine, linewidth = 3)
plt.plot(x,cosine, linewidth = 3)
plt.xlabel('time')
plt.ylabel('curve')
plt.grid('true')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Did you read the docstrings for `sin` and `cos`? Is it expecting degrees or radians?

Comment: Also, what problem are you encountering?

Comment: Your result looks OK, the only thing that might be worth changing is the grid interval along x axis (every 90 instead of every 100)

Comment: The thing is with the code I posted it works graphing both curves but I didnt quite understand how I made it work really so I was hoping people could point out any problems I have in the code or if it is actually doing what I want it to do, sorry if it is too much to ask for

Comment: @Błotosmętek with `numpy.linspace` the third argument is the number of values, not the spacing between them

Comment: You might want to head over to the Code Review site or the maplotlib forums for help. Stack Overflow is for focused, specific problems related to programming.

Comment: @PaulH I am talking about the grid. You know, those grey vertical lines. It would make more sense to have them at -360, -270, -180, -90, 0, 90 etc.

Comment: I did not know there was such a place to review my code thanks for the heads up I will use it when this kind of trouble presents itself again

Comment: `plt.xticks(np.arange(-360, 361, 90))` would set the markings on the x-axis as well as the position of the vertical grid lines